# locking logic for frequently queried view on frequently updated tables - please advise?

Tags: sql, view, locking, teradata

We face the following situation (Teradata):
Business layer frequently executes long-running queries on Table X_Past UNION ALL Table X_Today.

Table X_Today gets updated frequently, say once every 10 minutes. X_Past only once after midnight (per full-load).

- Writing process should not block reading process.
- Writing should happen as soon as new data is available.

Proposed approach:
2 "Today" and a "past" table, plus a UNION ALL view that selects from one of them based on the value in a load status table.

X_Today_1
X_Today_0
X_Past

loading process with load in X_Today_1 and set the active_table value in the load status table to "X_Today_1"
next time it will load X_Today_0 and set the active_table value to "X_Today_0" 
etc.

The view that is used to select on the table will be built as follows:

```
 select *
   from X_PAST

 UNION ALL

 select td1.*
   from X_Today_1  td1
        , ( select active_table from LOAD_STATUS ) active_tab1
  where active_tab1.te_active_table = 'X_Today_1'

UNION ALL

 select td0.*
   from X_Today_0 td0
        , ( select active_table from STATUS_LOG ) active_tab0
  where active_tab1.te_active_table = 'X_Today_0'
```

my main questions:

- when executing the select, will there be a lock on ALL tables, or only on those that are actually accessed for data? Since because of the where clause, data from one of the Today_1/0 tables will always be ignored and this table should be availablew for loading;
- do we need any form of locking or is the default locking mechanism that what we want (which I suspect it is)?
- will this work, or am I overlooking something?

It is important that the *loading* process will wait in case the *reading* process takes longer than 20 minutes and the loader is about to refresh the second table again. The *reading* process should never really be blocked, except maybe by itself.

Any input is much appreciated...

thank you for your help.

Comment: By the way, I love your profile photo :) It looks very familiar, I have a similar image on my blog: https://vivaelfalafel.wordpress.com/about/

Comment: I would tend to think that if your queries are taking 20+ minutes, you should be figuring out why that's happening, instead of trying to work around it.  20 minutes is a really slow query.

Comment: @ravioli haha what a coincidence :)

Comment: @Andrew we can't look into the future... I have no idea what business analysts are going to come up with that has them blocking everything for a significant time. However we cannot afford creating a structure that depends on them behaving well.

Comment: ps that is not to say that our data structures incl indexes, stats, compression etc shouldn't ready to deal with some abuse :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments to your questions:

1. Depending on the query structure, the Optimizer will try to get the default locks (in this case a `READ` lock) at different levels -- most likely table or row-hash locks.  For example, if you do a `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE PI_column = 'value'`, you should get a row-hash lock and not a table lock.

   Try running an `EXPLAIN` on your `SELECT` and see if it gives you any locking info.  The Optimizer might be smart enough to determine there are 0 rows in one of the joined tables and reduce the lock requests.  If it still locks both tables, see the end of this post for an alternative approach.
2. Your query written as-is will result in `READ` locks, which would block any `WRITE` requests on the tables.  If you are worried about locking issues / concurrency, have you thought about using an explicit `ACCESS` lock?  This would allow your `SELECT` to run without ever having to wait for your write queries to complete.  This is called a "dirty read", since there could be other requests still modifying the tables while they are being read, so it may or may not be appropriate depending on your requirements.
3. Your approach seems feasible.  You could also do something similar, but instead of having two `UNIONs`, have a single "X_Today" view that points to the "active" table.  After your load process completes, you could re-point the view to the appropriate table as needed via a `MACRO` call:

```
-- macros (switch between active / loading)
REPLACE MACRO switch_to_today_table_0 AS 
REPLACE VIEW X_Today AS SELECT * FROM X_Today_0;

REPLACE MACRO switch_to_today_table_1 AS 
REPLACE VIEW X_Today AS SELECT * FROM X_Today_1;

-- SELECT query
SELECT * FROM X_PAST UNION ALL SELECT * FROM X_Today;

-- Write request
MERGE INTO x_today_0...;

-- Switch active "today" table to must recently loaded one
EXEC switch_to_today_table_0;
```

You'd have to manage which table to write to (or possible do that using a view too) and which "switch" macro to call within your application.

One thing to think about is that having two physical tables that logically represent the same table (i.e. should have the same data) may potentially allow for situations where one table is missing data and needs to be manually synced.

Also, if you haven't looked at them already, a few ideas to optimize your `SELECT` queries to run faster: row partitioning, indexes, compression, statistics, primary index selection.

Comment: hi ravioli, what a great coincidence, about the profile pic:)

Comment: thanks for the suggestions - 1) The solution only works because of how the source data is organized, latest timestamp will always give us the full daily delta since source DB upserts ALL records of current day with an updated timestamp so our last load is always the best  2) we WANT to block any concurrent WRITES, and NEVER allow dirty reads, so that while reading is on _1, we write on _0 but in the extreme case where _1 still is being read 10 minutes later (next select would jump to _0).. the write has to wait. 3) we cannot afford to drop the view every 10 minutes - we need 100% uptime :)

Comment: ps I agree with your suggestions to optimize selects. I hope the ad-hoc business analysts and their reporting tools know them as well... all we do is provide a bunch of data, but i agree there is always a lot that can be done to allow querying :)

Comment: Great minds think alike :)  Yes, see if you can do some performance tweaks to speed up your query -- 20 minutes is a long time like Andrew mentions.  Probably a better alternative to the "replace view" method is to move your `SELECT` into an `SP` where you decide which "latest" table to query the data from, possibly via an input parameter.